# jquery hide show outside error

Tags: jquery

i am trying to make onclick work outside and inside for div hide and show, but its getting fired again and again!

html code

```
<div id='test' class='hidden'>test</div>
```

js code:

```
function divcode(){
$('#test').live('click', function() {
if($('#test').hasClass('hidden')){ $(this).removeClass(); $(this).addClass('show'); $("#test").show();
}
});}

$("html").click(function(){ 
if($('#test').hasClass('show')){ $('#test').removeClass(); $('#test').addClass('hidden'); $("#topuserdetails").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need something like this:

```
$test = $('#test');

$('#test').click(function(event) {
    if ($test.hasClass('hidden')) {
        $test.removeClass();
        $test.addClass('show');
        $("#topuserdetails").show();
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$("html").click(function() {
    if ($test.hasClass('show')) {
        $test.removeClass();
        $test.addClass('hidden');
        $("#topuserdetails").hide();
    }
});
```

`event.stopPropagation();` is essentials so that when you click `$('test')` the `$('html')` click event doesn't fire too.

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/xXBEY/8/

Answer (score 0):

It might because initially your div has no class. add either of those 2 classes to your div and then try.
Something like this:

`<div id="test" class="show">Demo</div>`
and also make a jsFiddle if this still remains unsolved, so that you can get better responses.

Comment: Could you make a JSFiddle of it and provide us a link please?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement most of your required functionality by chaining the jQuery calls like so:

#### JavaScript

```
$('html').click(function() {
    $('#test').toggleClass('hidden').toggleClass('show').toggle();
});
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="test" class="show">test</div>
```

The `click()` event is bound to the `HTML` element but the JavaScript always manipulates the `<div id="test"/>` element directly.

I also added this as [**a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EWeB9/)